# How can I draw a line from a point to a polygon edge and then get the line's length in sf in R?

Tags: r, geospatial, r-sf

There are some other posts out there *related* to this one, such as these: [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66080995/create-lines-within-polygons-at-given-points), [Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25742903/vertical-lines-in-a-polygon-shapefile), [Post 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55393494/find-nearest-distance-from-spatial-point-with-direction-specified). However, none of them deliver what I am hoping for. What I want is to be able to draw a line segment from a specific point (a sampling location) to the edge of a polygon fully surrounding that point (a lake border) in a specific direction ("due south" aka downward). I then want to measure the length of that line segment in between the sampling point and the polygon edge (really, it's only the distance I want, so if we can get the distance without drawing the line segment, so much the better!). Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like functionality to do this already exists within the `sf` package: [See closed issue here](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/321).

I *suspect*, though, that this is possible through a modification of the solution offered here: [See copy-pasted code below, modified by me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66080995/create-lines-within-polygons-at-given-points). However, I am pretty lousy with the tools in `sf`--I got as far as making line segments that just go from the points themselves to the southern extent of the polygon, intersecting the polygon at some point:

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(
  lon = c(119.4, 119.4, 119.4, 119.5, 119.5),
  lat = c(-5.192,-5.192,-5.167,-5.167,-5.191)
)

polygon <- df %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast("POLYGON")

plot(polygon)

df2 <- data.frame(lon = c(119.45, 119.49, 119.47),
                  lat = c(-5.172,-5.190,-5.183))

points <- df2 %>%
  st_as_sf(coords = c("lon", "lat"), crs = 4326) %>%
  summarise(geometry = st_combine(geometry)) %>%
  st_cast("MULTIPOINT")

plot(points, add = TRUE, col = "red")

# Solution via a loop

xmin <- min(df$lat)

m = list()
# Iterate and create lines
for (i in 1:3) {
  m[[i]] = st_linestring(matrix(
    c(df2[i, "lon"],
      df2[i, "lat"],
      df2[i, "lon"],
      xmin),
    nrow = 2,
    byrow = TRUE
  ))
}
test = st_multilinestring(m)

# Result is line MULTILINESTRING object

plot(test, col = "green", add = TRUE)
```

[image: progress so far]

But now I can't figure out how to use `st_intersection` or any such function to figure out where the intersection points are. Most of the trouble lies, I think, in the fact that what I'm creating is not an `sf` object, and I can't figure out how to get it to be one. I assume that, if I could figure out where the segments intersect the polygon (or the most-northern time they do so, ideally), I could somehow measure from the intersection points to the sampling points using a function like `st_distance`. Since lake polygons are often *really* complex, though, it's possible a segment will intersect the polygon multiple times (such as if there is a peninsula south of a given point), in which case I figure I can find the "furthest north" intersection point for each sampling point and use that or else take the minimum such distance for each sampling point.

Anyhow, if someone can show me the couple of steps I'm missing, that'd be great! I feel like I'm so close and yet so far...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this approach, loosely inspired by my earlier post about [lines from points](https://www.jla-data.net/eng/lines-from-points/)

To make it more reproducible I am using the well known & much loved North Carolina shapefile that ships with {sf} and a data frame of three semi-random NC cities.

What the code does is:

- iterates via for cycle over the dataframe of cities
- creates a line starting in each city ("observation") and ending on South Pole
- intersects the line with dissolved North Carolina
- blasts the intersection to individual linestrings
- selects the linestring that passes within 1 meter of origin
- calculates the lenght via `sf::st_lenghth()`
- saves the the result as a {sf} data frame called `res` (short for result :)

I have included the actual line in the final object to make the result more clear, but you can choose to omit it.

```
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

shape <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>%  # included with sf package
  summarise() %>% 
  st_transform(4326) # to align CRS with cities

cities <- data.frame(name = c("Raleigh", "Greensboro", "Plymouth"),
                     x = c(-78.633333, -79.819444, -76.747778),
                     y = c(35.766667, 36.08, 35.859722)) %>% 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"), crs = 4326)

# a quick overview
ggplot() +
   geom_sf(data = shape) + # polygon of North Carolina
   geom_sf(data = cities, color = "red") # 3 cities
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

```
# now here's the action!!!
for (i in seq_along(cities$name)) {
  
  # create a working linestring object
  wrk_line <- st_coordinates(cities[i, ]) %>% 
    rbind(c(0, -90)) %>% 
    st_linestring() %>% 
    st_sfc(crs = 4326) %>% 
    st_intersection(shape) %>% 
    st_cast("LINESTRING") # separate individual segments of multilines
  
  first_segment <- unlist(st_is_within_distance(cities[i, ], wrk_line, dist = 1))  
  
  # a single observation
  line_data <- data.frame(
    name = cities$name[i],
    length = st_length(wrk_line[first_segment]),
    geometry = wrk_line[first_segment]
  )
  
  # bind results rows to a single object
  if (i == 1) {
    res <- line_data
    
  } else {
    res <- dplyr::bind_rows(res, line_data)
    
  } # /if - saving results
  
  
} # /for

# finalize results
res <- sf::st_as_sf(res, crs = 4326) 
  
# result object    
res
# Simple feature collection with 3 features and 2 fields
# Geometry type: LINESTRING
# Dimension:     XY
# Bounding box:  xmin: -79.81944 ymin: 33.92945 xmax: -76.74778 ymax: 36.08
# Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
#         name        length                       geometry
# 1    Raleigh 204289.21 [m] LINESTRING (-78.63333 35.76...
# 2 Greensboro 141552.67 [m] LINESTRING (-79.81944 36.08...
# 3   Plymouth  48114.32 [m] LINESTRING (-76.74778 35.85...

# a quick overview of the lines
ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = shape) + # polygon of North Carolina
  geom_sf(data = res, color = "red") # 3 lines
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice answer! Thanks for sharing... and for the touch of humour! Always a pleasure to read your posts. Cheers

Comment: Hi @Jindra Lacko--a very nice answer! Out of curiosity, what happens if one of the points is over on the east side of the state, where the border is very irregular and the line segments would likely intersect the polygon multiple times? It'd be useful to know how to select just the "first" (from north) of these intersections since in my working case this will happen frequently with lake polygons. Cheers!

Comment: Apparently, this is what happens--I put in the coordinates of Suffolk, NC in the `cities` assignment to get this: https://imgur.com/a/Sb7ExnV. You can then use `st_length(st_cast(res, "LINESTRING"))` to get back the lengths of the smaller segments (though seemingly not a logical order?).  Maybe there's a more elegant way...

Can you clarify: 1) Can you put *any* point inside the `rbind()` call here to change the direction/bearing? and 2) What is `st_intersection()` actually doing here? I think addressing these two questions would improve your answer even further (though it's already great)!

Comment: @Bajcz I have updated the answer in light of your comments; I have added a piece of code that blasts the intesection of the line and "lake" from a single multilinestring to multiple linestrings, and then the distance and geometry are selected for the line that contains origin (or rather passes within 1 metre from origin, because floating point math)

Comment: If anyone is finding this post via Google and wants to calculate fetch on lake polygons, I have been successful in amending the code in this fantastic answer to do this for any point within a lake. The key is the `rbind` call--replace the first value in that call with a sequence of values between -180 and 180 to rotate the segments 360 degrees and then find the longest opposing segment pairing that produces the max length. It's awesome!